# Why is this set in the complex plane not connected?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

My initial intuition said it was connected but the back of the book is saying otherwise and I don't know why. Consider $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\;\text{ s.t.}\;|z| \leq 5 \;\text{ and }\;|\Im(z)| \geq 1\}$.

Comment: Can you draw a picture of the set? If it doesn't *look* disconnected, then you've drawn the picture wrong.

Comment: **Edit:** Whoops. <strike>It is connected. It's the portion of the closed disk of radius $5$ which lies on or above the horizontal line $y=1$. Are you sure you have the problem right?</strike>

Comment: @MPW: No: it’s that **and** the portion of the disk lying on or below the line $y=-1$. Notice the absolute value signs in the second requirement.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : Ah, yes, I now see it's $|Im(z)|$ and not just $Im(z)$. Thanks for the correction, +1.

Comment: @MPW: You’re welcome; I had the same oversight at first!

Comment: Yes I was having the same issue when I graphed it

Answer (score 3):

Observe that if we call your set $\;D\;$ , then

$$D=\left\{z\in\Bbb C\;/\;|z|\le5\;\text{and}\;\text{Im}\,z\ge1\right\}\cup\left\{z\in\Bbb C\;/\;|z|\le5\;\text{and}\;\text{Im}\,z\le-1\right\}$$

Check now that both sets on the right side above are non-empty, closed (in $\;D\;$, not only in $\;\Bbb C;$) and disjoint.

Comment: @copper.hat I think it is. I though will edit, since thinking of your comment I guess it may be clearer to remark they're closed **in** $\;D\;$ ...and thus also open there, of course.

Comment: Sorry, sloppy thinking on my part.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you anyway. I think now it is neater.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a picture of your set:

[image: disconnected set]

As you can see, the two regions are disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U = \{ z | \operatorname{im} z > {1 \over 2} \}$,
$V = \{ z | \operatorname{im} z < - {1 \over 2} \}$.

$U,V$ are open, non empty, disjoint and the set is contained in $U \cup V$.

Answer (score 0):

The set $|\Im(z)| > 1$ is the union of *two* disjoint half-planes; i.e., is disconnected.  Each of its connected components meets the disc $|z| < 5$.